# Get total number of rows while using limit clause

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am querying my table to achieve pagination but I do not know the total number of rows in the table.

```
select name from table where id = 1 limit 0, 10
```

Is there a way to find out the total number of rows that would have returned if I had not used limit clause without querying for total count.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQLite computes results on the fly when they are actually needed.

The only way to get the total count is to run the actual query (or better, `SELECT COUNT(*)`) without the `LIMIT`.

Comment: So, I need to run two queries. First for getting the total count and other with limit cause.

Comment: Depending on your application, it might be a better idea to not show the total count at all.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on which back end technology you are using. In PHP, [mysql_num_rows()](https://www.php.net/mysql_num_rows) returns number of rows without actually fetching the data.

Comment: Tejas, I am using sqlite3 database and am talking about sql query to fetch the data.

Comment: Yup. Got it after watching the other answer. However, I believe pagination is for some web application? If you have only SQLite, CL's answer is correct.